# what is the difference between the two split function 1) str.Split(" "c) 2) str.Split(" ".ToCharArray)

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, split

Suppose String str is assigned as

```
str="abc 123 xyz"
```

what is the difference between the two split function

1. `str.Split(" "c)`
2. `str.Split(" ".ToCharArray)`

Comment: `" ".ToCharArray` allows multiple split characters, `" "c` is just a single character. Note that another option is `str.Split(" ")` which splits on exactly that whole string. When in doubt, [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Charlieface you must have `Option Strict Off`. When not strict, the string passed is converted to a char array, and that will have unintended consequences. The proper way to split on a whole string is with [Split(String, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)) for example

Comment: @djv Righto, I meant `str.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: I realize we don't know which version of .NET OP is asking about. Well our discussion is related to .NET standard / core. In .NET Framework one would need to put that string in an array

Answer (score -1):

For a call like

```
string[] subs = s.Split(' ');
```

there is no difference like documented at [String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#example):

> The following examples show three different overloads of
> String.Split(). The first example calls the Split(Char[]) overload and
> passes in a single delimiter.

The function [Split(Char[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-char())) is implemented quite general and allows to split by multiple characters if defined:

> Splits a string into substrings based on specified delimiting characters.

Comment: The question was asked in vb.net. The syntax you used (c#) may not be recognizable to people not versed in both languages.